# Get the name of a function in C

Tags: c, function, macros

I'm implementing a test library and I want to be able to print the test functions, which fail. Therefore I need a way to get the name of the failing function. I know there are predefined identifiers like `__func__` and `__FUNCTION__`, but they only give me the name of the last executed function. I also don't want to use those identifiers inside the unit test functions, but in the procedure, which runs all the tests.

I posted an example, which uses an imaginary function called `function_name`. Is there any macro or something else available for this purpose?

```c
/** Description
 *      This function calls a number of unit tests and print the results.
 *      Please note the imaginary function 'function_name'.
 * 
 *  Parameters:
 *      tests: Function pointers to unit tests
 *      number_tests: The number of tests to run
 */
void run_tests(unit_test* tests, unsigned int number_tests) {
    int number_passed = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_tests; i++) {
        // Execute the unit test and get the result
        test_result result = (*tests[i])();

        if (result == TEST_PASSED)
            number_passed++;
        else
            printf("Test %s failed!\n", function_name(*tests[i]));
    }

    printf("%d/%d passed tests, %d failed tests\n", number_passed,
        number_tests, number_tests - number_passed);
}
```

Comment: Fyi, when you said, *"they only give me the name of the last executed function"* you probably meant "they only give me the name current function".  You're already reaping the functions by address into `tests` (somewhere not shown). One alternative if to reap them into an array of `struct func { int (*pfn)(); const char *fname; }` and stringize the name whilst your loading up `tests`, reporting that instead.

Comment: It would seem that your test variable should simply be a struct indeed. The solution to the problem should be where you set up the `unit_test` array. Otherwise since you have a unison API where everything returns a `test_result`, why can't that contain a copy of the `__func__` string?

Comment: I don't understand how `function_name(*tests[i])` makes sense however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using C, a good solution seems to lie in the use of the preprocessor, and in the use of a richer structure for the `unit_test` type. That is: instead of simply having a function pointer, it would contain also the function name, like:

```
struct _unit_test {
   int (*func)();
   char* func_name;
};
typedef struct _unit_test unit_test;
```

A macro like this would help it be populated

```
#define ptr_name(x) {x, #x}
```

And the initialization of the `tests` array could be

```
unit_tests tests[] = {ptr_name(func1), ptr_name(func2)};
```

You would have to change the following line of your code

```
test_result result = (*tests[i])();
```

to

```
test_result result = tests[i].func();
```

And the failed result line to

```
printf("Test %s failed!\n", tests[i].func_name);
```

Comment: Cool, thank you. Using a macro to automatically transform the variable name of the input to a string (char pointer) helped me!